# Convert CCYYMMDD to MM/DD/YYYY vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How can I convert a date in the string format CCYYMMDD (i.e. 20120624) to MM/DD/YYYY (i.e. 06/24/2012)?

I am trying this but its not parsing, throwing an exception jDate is not a valid datetime format

```
Public Shared Function ConvertJDateToDate(ByVal jDate As String) As String
        Dim d As Date = Date.ParseExact("yyyyMMdd", jDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        Dim newText As String = d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        Return newText
    End Function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your arguments are in the wrong order.

You want this:

```
Dim d As Date = DateTime.ParseExact( jDate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture )
```

Comment: how do I take off the time?

Comment: What do you mean by "take off the time"? Your `ToString` method doesn't include any time specifiers (`HH`, `mm`, `ss`, etc).